# Why cant we create an object of base class in a derived class function if base class constructor is protected

Tags: c++, constructor

Forgive me if the question is a duplication....I was not able to get a satisfying answer, so posting the questing in my way....

Consider the sample code

```
class Base {
protected:
     Base() {}
};
class Derived:public Base {
public:
     void func() {
        Base obj;
     }
};
```

The above code will thow a compilation error saying the constructor of Base is protected.
But if I create an Object of Derived class in main the constructor of Base class is getting called( I know its called internally by the Derived class constructor), which means Base class constructor can be called from a Derived class function.
Then why we are not able to create an Base class object within a derived class function...?

And one more thing....is there any other way to instantiate an object of a class whose constructor in protected, other than inside a  method of the same class(as we do while creating Singleton )...?

Answer (score 2):

The access type `protected` only grants access to "your own" members inherited from the parent class. Unlike e.g. Java, C++ has quite a strict interpretation of that concept, allowing you to only access inherited members of the same instance.

By using the constructor you are technically trying to access non-public implementation details of another instance, which is forbidden.

Comment: So is there any other way to instantiate an object of a class whose constructor in protected, other than from a static public method of the Base class(ie. Creating Singleton )

Answer (score 2):

A mistake is to think that you are validly trying to access a protected base class member. You're not doing that. You're trying to create an instance of a class with a constructor marked as protected. By marking a constructor as protected, you are specifically forbidding construction of an instance of that class. That is only possible inside a derived class's constructor. And that is why you found it to work in the `main()` program.

The only way to create an instance of `Base` without removing the protected specifier, is to create an instance of `Derived` which "is a" instance of Base. Or create another derived class that doesn't add any overridden behaviour to `Base'.